# (MEF) Does composition have to happen at startup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, composition

I ask this question because I have been tasked with creating a framework so that we can have an MVC website that, when the user logs in, loads "plugins" from the database by pulling their assemblies out and loading them in such a way so as to be used.  These plugins can be small widgets that appear in a portion of a page, or full blown sections of the app.

I chose MEF because it looked (and still looks) to be the perfect key to my lock, as it were, but I keep getting tripped up on the fact that everything happens when the app starts up.  I already have another question somewhat related to this issue ([located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334701/updating-mef-catalog-at-runtime)), but that is for a specific issue.  My issue is that when the user logs in, that's when I need all my composition to happen, after I've gone to the database to get all of the plugins (.dll files) that the user has installed for their account.

So my question is this: As it related to MEF, does composition absolutely have to happen at startup, or can I have it so that all of my composition happens after the user logs in?  This is crucial to this project.  And before it is asked, the entire site is locked down by authentication.  The only thing an unregistered user will see is the login page and nothing more.  So the site could have a completely different look (and available functionality) based on the user that is logged in.

Or am I simply asking too much, technically speaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say composition should happen once. and if you have all information after a successful login then do your composition after the login. i go that way too in my projects (Login -> MEF -> Show APP)

Comment: I think you hit my issue on the head.  I've been trying to do all my MEF composition at startup, but separate it all by user, when what needs to happen is the user logs in, THEN I do all my MEF composition magic, storing the composition container in session, then let my app do what it does.  I think that's the key.  Thanks for the tip!  My head just wasn't in the right place.  :)